# What Stack Exchange site is most suitable for a question regarding Microsoft Deployment Toolkit?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, serverfault

I am having issues with importing WIFI drivers into Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 
(for deploying Windows 7).

Where would be a suitable place to ask my question? I guessed that Server Fault would be suitable but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it fits [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) for two reasons in their ['What topics can I ask about here'](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic):

> Server and Workstation operating systems, hardware, and software.
>
> Operations, maintenance, and monitoring.

Maintaining driver packages is a typical operation for an administrator, so it fits here.